# CKEditor inline with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ckeditor, body-parser

I'm trying to create minimalistic content management system with ckeditor using node and express as a server. I would definitely want to implement the inline editing capabilities of ckeditor, but I'm having no success in sending the data to server and finally to nosql (mongodb) database.

I would like to have multiple inline editors within a page and to save to my database them simultaneously upon a POST event. I have my editor instances in invividual divs with an attribute contenteditable="true". Editor instances launch just fine, but when I'm trying to grab the data in my controller, all I have is an empty object. I can get the data from input fields, but then I lose  the inline editing features. I've tried tinkering with bodyparser, but no success. All my divs containing the editable content lay under a HTML form element.

I would be more than happy is someone could at least point me to a general direction of how to accomplish this. Sorry if I was unable to make my self clear posting this question :)

tldr; How can I parse data from HTML elements, other than input-fields and text areas, in node/express with bodyparser?

Answer (score 0):

Content of non-input fields won't be posted in a form, so you can't do that. A couple options come to mind:

1. Use JavaScript to update hidden inputs on the page as those divs change. Updated content will be posted.
2. Use JavaScript to make the POST, on save grab the contents, post them to the server, and then after that make the redirect from client side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have thought that, as you said it, it's impossible to post non-input fields. Option 1 seems to be reasonable for my case so I'll give it a try.